# Bring Default Selected Recycler View item to center

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

[image]

I have this horizontal Linear Layout for dates recycler view. I am selected the current date by default in the recycler view. I want this selected date to be in center so that the user is aware that he have previous dates as well. I found no help so far.

Comment: share your code

Comment: @NavneetKrishna is the code really required ?
i just want to bring this selected item to the center of the screen .
I saw a few things on Layout Manager's methods of finding first and last item on screen but they did not help me.

Comment: Did you find the solution?